# Calc 2 question about a function that determines speed?

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't know where to start. I know a function for speed will be a derivative of some sort but beyond that I'm just not sure what concepts I should be using to solve this one.

Here's the question, just without the included triangle diagram:

A movie crew is working on a scene that involves filming a car moving at a high speed. For one perspective, a camera is positioned and fixed at a spot 50 feet from the car’s path (see point C below). Construct a function $s(x)$ that determines the speed (in radians per second) at which the camera should turn to keep the car in frame when the car is at point B, which is $x$ feet from the point on the path that is closest to the camera (point A). Assume the car is moving at 90 miles per hour in the positive $x$ direction.

Diagram based on the description:

C

|

| 50 ft

|

A---------B

```
    x
```

Comment: It is difficult to get an idea of how to help you without the diagram from the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You have a right triangle, $50$ and $x$ being the legs.  The side $x$ is lengthening at 90 mph.  What is that in feet/second?  If $\theta$ is the angle between $50$ and the hypotenuse, you are being asked for $\frac {d\theta}{dt}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I know I've got to take the derivative somewhere and I've got that it's moving 7920 feet per second, but I'm not sure what I plug that value into.

Comment: @Bill:  where do you get 7920 ft/sec?  90 miles/hour is much slower than that.  I think you forgot one division by $60$.  You need to write an equation $\theta = $some function of $x$, then use the chain rule $\frac {d\theta}{dt}=\frac {d\theta}{dx}\frac {dx}{dt}$

Comment: thanks for catching that. you're right, it's 132 feet per second.

Answer (score 0):

This question involves related rates. You will want to use the triangle to relate the quantities of the angle ACB to the position $x$. The side with length x and length 50 form a right triangle with the angle ACB.

Comment: Thanks @Kris . Since I've got a right triangle, I'm assuming I can use the Pythagorean formula but because I only have one side given plus a rate of 7920 feet/second for x, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Bill Since the problem states they want an answer in radians per second, you will actually want to use an angle identity: tangent, sine or cosine depending on your diagram. From your description, I think tangent will be the best bet.